# Restructuring JSON to use with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a JSON file structured like this

```
[
 {
    "firstKey": {
        "item": "string",
        "item2": "string",
        "item3": "string"
    }
 },
 {
    "secondKey": {
        "item": "string",
        "item2": "string",
        "item3": "string"
    }
 }, 
.
.
.

]
```

Is there anyway to change it to

```
 "firstKey": {
  "item": "string",
  "item2": "string",
  "item3": "string"
},
"secondKey": {
  "item": "string",
  "item2": "string",
  "item3": "string"
},
.
.
.
```

so that I can directly copy it to my JSON and import it to the Firebase Real-time Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's advisable for you to change it to the second format. You could map through the array in the first and insert the values into your firebase database.

Example:

```
const my_array = [
 {
    "Key": {
        "item": "string",
        "item2": "string",
        "item3": "string"
    }
 },
 {
    "Key": {
        "item": "string",
        "item2": "string",
        "item3": "string"
    }
 }
]


my_array.map((value)=>{
 //you can now insert value into your database 
})
```